# Is double derivative of a tensor component with respect to time itself a tensor?

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus, differentiation

Can you please clear my doubt that if we take double derivative of a tensor component with respect to time, will the resulting quantity be a tensor or not?

Comment: Which time? Proper time or time of some arbitrary observer? Also what do you mean by tensor, a tensor field (i.e. defined at all points in space-time)? Or a tensor linked to the moving object, e.g. four-velocity (tangent to the world-line)? It may help to make this question more specific, currently there are too many possible answers (IMHO). Finally, is this question about special relativity, or classical mechanics (this would resolve the 'which time' question)?

Answer (score 0):

If time is not one of the co-ordinates of the tensor (for example, if the tensor is a [Cartesian tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_tensor)) then, yes, taking the derivative of the tensor component-wise with respect to time will result in another tensor. And if you can do it once then you can do it twice (as long as any functions of time involved are sufficiently smooth).

If time is one of the co-ordinates of the tensor (for example, if the tensor is a [four-tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-tensor)) then things are more complicated. In general, taking the partial derivative of the tensor component-wise with respect to time will *not* result in another tensor. To produce another tensor you will need to take the [covariant derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariant_derivative) with respect to time.